# Selecting (SKU)s and (QTY)s using php($sql) which (SKU)s are in Table A but not in Table B

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have couple tables in mssql server and the below is table i have.

Table A have QTY, SKU, ItemID - have 50,000 SKU
Table B have QTY, SKU - have 10,000 SKU - these sku are in Table A 
(Table A have more data than Table B)

and i want to select (SKU)s and (QTY)s using php($sql) which (SKU)s are in Table A but not in Table B

Thank you so much guys in advance!

Comment: You could use [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to create some example of your data grid and post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question nearly uses the exact syntax required.  Something like this should work.

```
select sku, qty from tableA where tableA.sku not in (select sku from tableB)
```